# Model not saved after training in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, save, classification, torch

I encounter the following problem.
I perform an increasing cross-validation; I have 20 subjects in my dataset and try to classify images. I start with 3 subjects and perform a cross-validation with k=3; that is I train 3 different models and validate on the subject left out. And this is what I do for 4, 5, ..., 20 drivers. Hence, I have a lot of models trained.

Now I wanted to check the performance of all models on another dataset, but for some reason the accuracy is the same for all models, which must be a bug somewhere.

I already use `copy.deepcopy()`, so I must have an error somewhere else.
I'm open for any hints!

Here is the code for the training function:

```
def train_model(model, num_classes, dirname, trainloader, valloader, trainset_size, valset_size, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, patience, min_delta, num_epochs, fold):


device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
since = time.time()

train_loss, train_acc, val_loss, val_acc = [], [], [], []

best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
best_acc = 0.0
early_stopping = False
counter = 0
last_train_epoch = 0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            
    if early_stopping:
        print('\nEarly Stopping')
        break
        
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs))
    print('-' * 10)

    # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
    for phase in ['train', 'val']:
        if phase == 'train':
            model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            dataloader = trainloader
            dataset_size = trainset_size
        else:
            model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode
            dataloader = valloader
            dataset_size = valset_size

        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0

        # Iterate over data.
        for inputs, labels in dataloader:
            model = model.to(device)
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            #labels = labels.long().to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device) #test_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)

            # forward
            # track history if only in train
            with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            

                # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                if phase == 'train':
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()

            # statistics
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            
        if phase == 'train':
            scheduler.step()

        epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_size
        epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_size
        
        if phase == 'train':
            train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
            train_acc.append(epoch_acc)
        else:
            val_loss.append(epoch_loss)
            val_acc.append(epoch_acc)

        print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
            phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

        # early stopping
        if phase == 'val':
            if counter == patience:
                early_stopping = True
                break
                
            if epoch == 0:
                best_loss = epoch_loss
            else: 
                if best_loss >= epoch_loss + min_delta:
                    print('Validation loss decreased ({:.4f} --> {:.4f}).  Saving model ...'.format(best_loss,epoch_loss))
                    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), '{}/weights/model_fold_{}.pth'.format(dirname,fold))
                    last_train_epoch = epoch + 1
                    best_loss = epoch_loss
                    counter = 0
                else: 
                    counter += 1
            
time_elapsed = time.time() - since
print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
    time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

# load best model weights
model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
# save best model 

return model, train_acc, train_loss, val_acc, val_loss, last_train_epoch
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
    model = net
    model = model.to(device)   

    # train 
    [model, train_acc, train_loss, val_acc, val_loss, last_train_epoch] = train_model(model, num_classes, dirname,\
                                                                                     trainloader, valloader,\
                                                                                     trainset_size, valset_size,\
                                                                                     criterion, optimizer, \
                                                                                     exp_lr_scheduler, patience, \
                                                                                     min_delta, num_epochs, fold=val_index)
    
    # test model 
    [preds_val, labels_val, idx_false_val, pred_time_val_fold] = test(model, valloader)
    [preds_tr, labels_tr, idx_false_train, pred_time_train_fold] = test(model, trainloader)
    [preds_all, labels_all, idx_false_all, pred_time_all_fold] = test(model, allloader)
    print('Accuracy on all data: ', accuracy_score(labels_all, preds_all))
```

and for the sake of completeness, this is what the test() function looks like:

```
def test(model, dataloader):
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
#device = torch.device("cpu")

pred_labels, gt_labels, idx_false, pred_time = [], [], [], []

was_training = model.training
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        start_pred = time.clock() 
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        end_pred = time.clock()
        
        pred_time.append(end_pred-start_pred)

        for j in range(inputs.size()[0]):
            pred_labels.append(preds[j].item())  
            gt_labels.append(labels[j].item())   

    for i in range(len(pred_labels)):
        if pred_labels[i] != gt_labels[i]:
            idx_false.append(i)
             
    model.train(mode=was_training)
    
return pred_labels, gt_labels, idx_false, pred_time
```

**Edit**: It looks as if it always saves the same models even though I try to make sure that only the updated weights of the best model are saved.

Comment: Did you print this `'{}/weights/model_fold_{}.pth'.format(dirname,fold)` ? You need to check first the folders exist or not.

Comment: Yes, the folders exist. I also tried to  load the weights from the same path and applied them to the data; but got the same results.

Comment: Why not just save the `model.state_dict()` directly in the `if`? Or you have something else between it?

Comment: Actually providing how you call the `train()` might be helpful

Comment: I try to run it now with `model.state_dict()` inside the `if`

Comment: But it still returns the same model. I really cannot see what is going wrong there ...

Comment: Maybe add `best_model_wts = torch.load('{}/weights/model_fold_{}.pth'.format(dirname,fold))` before `model.load_state_dict()`? because you're not using the saved weight now and this will tell if the `copy.deepcopy` is the problem or not

Comment: Does the same model means exact same weights?

Comment: It's actually the same model that was saved ...

Comment: Did you print the `best_loss`?

Comment: Yes, the best_loss is decreasing, but for some reason it always saves the same model...